# convert text date to year+month for sorting (ie, 1/19/2019 to 201901)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a column called paiddate in my sql database (tests.db) table (triangle).  Its a text field that looks like `'1/19/2019'` for example.  In another column called paidmonth, I want something like `'201901'`, which would allow me to sort the data by year and month.  I tried -

```
def getYearMonth(s):
  return s.split("/")[0]+"-"+s.split("/")[2]
```

---

```
df['paidmonth']= df['paiddate'].apply(lambda x: getYearMonth(x))
```

which gave me 1-2019, which looks ok but does not sort by date.  It sorts numerically.  So 1-2019 would come right after 1-2018, instead of 12-2018.

Comment: It would be the same with string in format "yyyymm". Convert your string to corresponding dates (use strftime) and use dates or you may convert those dates to integers and fill your dataframe with them.

Comment: `d.split('/')[2] + format(int(d.split('/')[0]), '02d')`

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string date time to a datetime64 type using pandas.  Its smart enough to infer the format (month first or day first) by inspecting the string.  You can provide a formatter to it that may speed it up is that is a limiter for a very large data set.

```
import pandas as pd

# Make some unsorted dates as strings in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': ['1/19/2019', '1/12/2019', '12/1/2019', '6/7/2019', '7/6/2019']
})

# create a new column that converts the string to a datetime64
df['paidmonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# sort the data
df.sort_values('paidmonth', inplace=True)
df
```

**Answer 2:**

Ok, if you just want to create a separate column that is year-month,  you can first convert the string to a date (as in first answer),  then use the .dt.period() to make that date just year-month.

There are some advantages to keeping the full date,  since you can use the pandas times series (dataframe indexed by datetime) methods to group by month (or quarter,  or day,  or year...) and do any type of aggregation,  or even rolling functions on the time series. Example below sums the payment column by month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=400
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=n, freq='d'),
    'Payment': np.random.randint(20, 500, n)
})

# Make a column that is only the year and month
df['year-month'] = ts['Date'].dt.to_period('M') 
display(df.head())

# use the full date column to group by month ans sum the payments 
df_bymonth = df.set_index('Date').resample('m').apply({'Payment': 'sum'})
display(df_bymonth.head())
```

[image]

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Comment: This seems to convert to date including days.  I need to group my data by month, so I only want 201902, or 02-2019 sortable by date

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` with `dt.strftime`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = ['%s/19/2019' % i for i in range(1, 10)]
```

Sample data:

```
        col1
0  1/19/2019
1  2/19/2019
2  3/19/2019
3  4/19/2019
4  5/19/2019
5  6/19/2019
6  7/19/2019
7  8/19/2019
8  9/19/2019
```

Using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col1    col2
0  1/19/2019  201901
1  2/19/2019  201902
2  3/19/2019  201903
3  4/19/2019  201904
4  5/19/2019  201905
5  6/19/2019  201906
6  7/19/2019  201907
7  8/19/2019  201908
8  9/19/2019  201909
```